# Java setting cookies through stream

Tags: java, sockets, cookies

I am writing a webserver, and I need to set a cookie on the client's web browser.
I get a OutputStream through Socket.getOutputStream(), but I cannot find a way to send a header with it. I tried sending javascript code to set the cookie on the client side, but the cookies set that way are not being sent back to the server.
How can I set a cookie through the header/other way.

Comment: Read the help, particularly http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, then come back and ask a question that can be answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You send the response header right before the body:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
writer.println("HTTP/1.0 200 Ok");
writer.println("Set-Cookie key=value Max-Age=8640");
writer.println("Content-Type text/html");
writer.println()//important
//send your body here
writer.flush();//send message
```

Here's a list of HTTP response header fields https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields